# if I log in Guest session and someone connect on my web cam

Tags: webcam, guest-session

if I log in Guest session and someone connect on my web cam
and I leave and I enter the main account the person who logged in my web cam in the guest account could it see me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think main account person can see the webcam because we are switching between accounts and guest session scope will be up to that session only